# How can i use different columns as input in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to integrate the leaflet package produced map with the Rshiny package. I got it working if i select a particular column to plot but if i use two different columns it throws an error.

Here is my dataframe head

```
   Type Location.ID             Location_discription      Lat      Long Flood.path Sample
1 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes     A1
2 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes     A3
3 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes     A4
4 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes     A5
5 GBS_S         ANG Angels' rest, Columbia Gorge, OR 45.56383 -122.1523        Yes   ANG1
6 GBS_S         ANG Angels' rest, Columbia Gorge, OR 45.56383 -122.1523        Yes  ANG1b
  Structure.2 Structure.3
1        Blue       Green
2        Blue       Green
3        Blue       Green
4        Blue       Green
5        Blue       Green
6        Blue       Green
```

Here is my ui.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Population Structure on map"),

  # Side bar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("structure", "Select K for dispaly", choices = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
    ),

  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
  )
)
)
```

And server.R code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    dt <- reactive(
        switch(input$structure,
              "2" = Structure.2,
              "3" = Structure.3)
      )

    output$map <- renderLeaflet(
      leaflet(data = data_K2) %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lng = -106.1039361,lat = 50.543981, zoom = 4) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Long, popup = ~Location_discription, radius=2, color = ~dt(), fill = TRUE)
    )
})
```

The error i'm getting is this...

```
Error in .func() : object 'Structure.2' not found
```

But i can clearly see that `Structure.2` is present in my df. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have figured it out by myself.. Here is the fix

```
dt <- reactive(
        switch(input$structure,
              "2" = data$Structure.2,
              "3" = data$Structure.3)
      )
```